# Strange user accounts displayed

Tags: users

I was following [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/user-management.html) to manage my server's users & groups :

I have one group aside from the default "admin" called "guest".
I used the following commands to display the users & groups :

```
compget -u
compget -g
```

But it displays users that I didn't create ; like "ftp" and "syslog". 
Could somebody explains to me what's going on ? I'm new to ubuntu & server OS .
Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108447/70524

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Most of them are system daemons and can't actually log in, they
>   represent processes started by [the init system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init).  If you look at
>   `cat /etc/passwd`, you'll see them all listed.  The last field is the
>   default shell, which may be `/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false` indicating
>   their lack of login possibilities.  The forth field (each field is
>   separated by an `:`) is a comment that may provide some information
>   about their purpose (for more, see `man 5 passwd`, the 5 is important,
>   otherwise you'll get the section 1 `passwd` command; section numbers
>   are described in `man man`).
>
> [Daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) services<sup>1</sup>run in the background, often as
>   unprivileged users for security purposes -- this way undiscovered
>   vulnerabilities can't be used to gain root access, etc.   Some of them
>   use the generic `daemon` user, others create their own for more secure
>   compartmentalization.
>
> For example, Avahi is one such daemon, for broadcast and discovery of
>   network services (e.g. certain kinds of file sharing, I believe) on a
>   LAN.  NTP is another, for synchronizing the system clock with a WWW
>   reference server.  On Ubuntu, services such as this can be
>   enabled/disabled via **upstart** (an init system developed by
>   Canonical).
>
> `nobody` is a catch-all account for things intended to operate with no
>   privileges beyond just existing.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1.  The ["Notable service daemons in Unix-like systems"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29#Notable_service_daemons_in_Unix-like_systems)
>   section of that wikipedia article contains some things from your
>   list.</sup>

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108451)

Comment: Thanks for the quote & answer Tim ; it was pretty helpful. It makes much sense to append these services to encapsulated & private user accounts, now that's creative !